# Install and run Android apps on Ubuntu Touch via the Dalvik VM or via the Android Runtime?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, virtualization

I've used the Linux [SailFish](https://sailfishos.org) OS my on my old Jolla1 phone and I remember I could install and run Android apps via the [Alien Dalvik VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailfish_OS#Using_Android_software_running_on_Sailfish_OS).

By now, there is a companent called [AppSupport for Linux Platforms](https://jolla.com/appsupport) which, I quote, (from https://jolla.com/appsupport):

```
gives any embedded Linux-compatible platform capability to run Android apps
```

Is it possible to have the Dalvik VM or the Android Runtime, on another component which would enable us to run Android apps on Ubuntu Touch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing several people on UBports forum asking about how to access Android apps on Ubuntu Touch. UBports works on Ubuntu Touch since Canonical stopped continuing the project so here is what I found.

The link I am seeing below seems to have a solution with an app called WayDroid recently available in the OpenStore:

https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-and-run-android-applications

Here was the post where I found that link:

https://forums.ubports.com/topic/7021/waydroid-helper-app-a-collection-of-scripts-to-improve-the-waydroid-user-expierience/13?_=1639431304546

I encourage you to search more posts about it on: https://forums.ubports.com

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also found Anbox : https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/anbox.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Android apps, if you need to run desktop apps on UB Touch, Libertine is a stock app that can help with it. I haven't used it per say but here are instructions I found.

https://docs.ubports.com/en/latest/userguide/dailyuse/libertine.html